# Error when using Concat and Nginx Modules

Tags: nginx, module, puppet

I'm currently getting the following error when trying to use the Concat and Nginx modules provided by Puppet with my project:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: no parameter named 'selinux_ignore_defaults' (file: /etc/puppet/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp, line: 122) on Concat_file[/etc/nginx/conf.d/web1_socket-upstream.conf] (file: /etc/puppet/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp, line: 122) on node web-1
```

Module for Concat is at v7.3.3
Nginx is at v4.3.0
StdLib is at v8.5.0

The relevant code in the Concat module doesn't look like it's missing the `selinux_ignore_defaults` parameter:

```
  newparam(:selinux_ignore_defaults, boolean: true, parent: Puppet::Parameter::Boolean) do
    desc <<-DOC
      See the file type's selinux_ignore_defaults documentention:
      https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-selinux_ignore_defaults.
    DOC
  end
```

Nor is it missing from the parameters declaration on the Puppet side:

```
Optional[Boolean]                  $selinux_ignore_defaults = undef,
```

I'm at a loss as to why the error is occurring. Any thoughts?

Comment: So what's at and around the line cited in the diagnostic, /etc/puppet/modules/concat/manifests/init.pp, line: 122, in your particular Puppet installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to resolve this issue with updating other modules and restarting our long-running puppet server